# Apache camel with mina to proxy tcp messages

Tags: java, proxy, apache-camel, apache-mina

I am new with Apache Camel and I am trying to create a simple proxy that redirect all messages from localhost:3260 to localhost:3261 using Apache Mina. I am basing on some examples at internet (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jZE-YSHK_gw&sns=tw) and changing for what is my propose. In this example is a redirect of a file and I just changed to use mina protocol.

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.simple.MyRouteBuilder;
public class MainTcpApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MyRouteBuilder routeBuilder = new MyRouteBuilder();
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        try {
            context.addRoutes(routeBuilder);
            context.start();
            for (;;) {
                Thread.sleep(5 * 60 * 50000);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            context.stop();
        }
    }
}
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
public class MyTcpRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("mina:tcp://localhost:3260").to("mina:tcp://localhost:3261");
    }
}
```

In my example I started a target iSCSI at 3261 "target name: iqn.2014-06.iscsi-dev:disk1 loaded. Address: 127.0.0.1 - port: 3261" and I am trying to connect through 3260.

```
iscsiadm -m node --login -T iqn.2014-06.ustore-dev:disk1 -p 127.0.0.1:3260
Logging in to [iface: default, target: iqn.2014-06.ustore-dev:disk1, portal: 127.0.0.1,3260] (multiple)
iscsiadm: Could not login to [iface: default, target: iqn.2014-06.ustore-dev:disk1, portal: 127.0.0.1,3260].
iscsiadm: initiator reported error (8 - connection timed out)
iscsiadm: Could not log into all portals
```

I already could do it with http://netty.io/, but as I want a load balance I will need Apache Camel with Mina.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try from("mina:tcp://0.0.0.0:3260").to("mina:tcp://localhost:3261");

Comment: show this message -->> Failed to create route route1: Route(route1)[[From[mina:tcp://0.0.0.0:3260]] -> [To[mina:tc... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: mina://tcp://0.0.0.0:3260 due to: No component found with scheme: mina

Comment: if I use Netty (from("netty:tcp://0.0.0.0:3260?sync=false").to("netty:tcp://localhost:3261?sync=false");) my app starts ok, but does not redirect. If I use netty alone without Camel it works well....

Comment: "No component found with scheme: mina" means that you don't have camel-mina dependency in your classpath. or it somehow not registered in context

Comment: Can you add logging into your route to make sure that your requests are basically go through the route from("netty:tcp://0.0.0.0:3260?sync=false"). **log("routing message ${body}")** .to("netty:tcp://localhost:3261?sync‌​=false");